# undefined method `load_routes!' using devise with mongoid in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I have a rails app using MongoDB. For connection with MongoDB I use the mongoid gem and now I want to integrate devise for authentication purposes.

I'm using

```
gem 'mongoid-devise'
gem 'devise'
```

After `bundle install` I do:

```
rails g devise:install
```

but it's throwing an error like below:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `load_routes!' for class `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet' (NameError)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:16:in `<class:RouteSet>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:2:in `<module:Routing>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise.rb:253:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/mongoid-devise-1.0.1/lib/devise.rb:253:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /home/user/Banter_IT/Project_Concept/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@new_banter_it/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me figure out what to do ASAP...

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `mongoid-devise` is very old one that's why it is not running with rails3

`devise` only will suffice as it supports mongoid also as you can see here [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).